# Multiple values inside SQL LIKE

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

[image: name 12ab_cd34 56ef_gh78 12ef_gh34]

This is working:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%ab_cd%'
```

How to include `'%ef_gh%'` in a single/multiple statement?

My try:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE IN ('%ab_cd_%', '%ef_gh%')
```

Comment: use `OR` between multiple `LIKE`

Comment: `OR` and multiple `LIKE` statements. There is no list functionality for `LIKE`.

Answer (score 5):

The `SIMILAR TO` operator matches a string expression, such as a column name, with a SQL standard regular expression pattern. A SQL regular expression pattern can include a set of pattern-matching metacharacters, including the two supported by the `LIKE` operator.

The `SIMILAR TO` operator returns true only if its pattern matches the entire string, unlike POSIX regular expression behavior, where the pattern can match any portion of the string.

`SIMILAR TO` performs a case-sensitive match.

NOTE:
Regular expression matching using SIMILAR TO is computationally expensive. We recommend using LIKE whenever possible, especially when processing a very large number of rows. For example, the following queries are functionally identical, but the query that uses LIKE runs several times faster than the query that uses a regular expression:

```sql
select count(*) from event where eventname SIMILAR TO '%(Ring|Die)%'; 
select count(*) from event where eventname LIKE '%Ring%' OR eventname LIKE '%Die%';
```